# Google indexing of dynamic content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, seo, sitemap.xml

I am making a website that will have a lot of user created content on it. Each user contribution can be accessed by urls such as:
http://example.com/3234
http://example.com/6455

I plan on using Google's sitemap crawler so that these pages can be indexed. I would be generating the sitemap.xml file daily.

The problem is the content of the page is generated dynamically with jquery and ajax, after the page is retrieved by a browser. So Google probably wont see any actual content in the page at the listed urls.

I read about this issue here:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot
It suggested making an html snapshot. So I have a few options. What are the pros and cons of each? or is there a better option?

Option 1
Add links to sitemap.xml like http://example.com/content.php?id=3234
This outputs the page's content to google in html. But when a browser goes to this page a (client-side) redirect takes them to http://example.com/3234

Option 2
At the server. Try to detect if the page is being accessed by a crawler and determine what to return.

Option 3
Try to just load the actual content into the element at the server. (requires significant redesign)

Comment: you should avoid #1 & #2 , because google may blacklist your page when you deliver different content to users & crawlers

Comment: option #2 works well if you follow the google guidelines that google will transform ajax page url's to `?_escaped_fragment=` query string, and then crawl that url. Requires setting proper meta tag. Then sitemap would have same URL's that users would see but crawlers will modify url with the query string automatically.  [google ajax spec](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)